# Android BLE write response

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

How do I get the write response in an android application of a write to a characteristic which has write response?

I can't find any callback for this. Only way I can think of is if onCharacteristicWrite status returns failed when the response is not received, difficult to confirm if it works like this though.

Note: I don't mean for Write Without Response, but the 4.9.3 Write Characteristic Value in Bluetooth Core Specification 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When onCharacteristicWrite is called with success status and the write type was Write With Response, that means you got the write response ;)

If no write response is received within 30 seconds the link gets disconnected.